# Android splash screen gray transition to activity

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen

I am currently working on an Android Application and I added a splash screen showing a logo at the beginning.

In order to ensure that the splash screen stays for the correct amount of time, I used the method of applying a theme to my splash screen activity and then, in the related Java class, I start the main activity (which has a white background, the same as the splash screen). The splash screen shows correctly and stays for the right amount of time, however, when transitioning to the main activity, the app shows a gray screen for about 1 second, before displying the fully loaded main activity. Do you know what could be the issue?

Here is the code in the style.xml file I am using:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/Trippy_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/Trippy_orange</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/TrippyGray</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/Trippy_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/Trippy_orange</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/TrippyGray</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

while this is the corresponding activity tag in the manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and this is the related activity code:

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);

        startActivity(new Intent(this, TrippyList.class).putExtra("comingActivity", false));

        finish();

    }

}
```

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found the problem. I implemented also a dark mode in the app and the code which handles the detection of the correct mode when the app launches was still in the main activity. The background seen in the transaction between the splash screen and the main activity was darker probably because my android system is in currently in dark mode.

Adding the dark/light mode setup in the splash screen solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this It worked for me.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
        countDownTimer= new CountDownTimer(2500, 500) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }
            public void onFinish() {

                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, TrippyList.class));
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                finish();

            }
        }.start();
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer! Unfortunately the gray screen is still there.... Just one more question, isn't in this case the screen time of the splash screen fixed?